# Vue children route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I was looking a way to make my static blog development more faster using `vue-router`, but I found a problem linking the children pages with the parent route.

```
    const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: '/about', name: 'About', component: About,
        children: [
          { 
            path: '/test', name: 'How test children link', component: prova }
        ]
    
      }
    ]
```

If I try to go on `localhost/about/test` address Vue can't find the page, but I can reach it if I go directly to `localhost/test`.

If I change the children path to

```
    path: '/about/test', name: 'How test children link', component: prova }
```

It works, but, I don't understand the utility of the child route.

What I don't understand about children route?

Comment: Have u checked out nuxtjs? It makes routing super ez

Comment: Shoten the name param of the route $router({name: 'about-*short-name-of-route*})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track. But you have to keep in mind that `/` means, and does, something.

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about', name: 'About', component: About,
    children: [
      { 
        path: 'test', name: 'AboutChild', component: TestComponent 
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So basically do NOT include a `/` when adding a path for children. And if you do, add the whole path so in this case: `path: '/about/test'`

And equally as important, you won't see the contents of `AboutChild` until you had a html tag called `<router-view />` in the About component.

Comment: Thank you so much! is working now! what does in this case the / ??

Comment: mmmhh...yes I understand what you mean, now I got it and in fact I have the child content in the navbar, another thing to fix :D